# Search result webpart shows no results

Tags: 2013, search-results

I want to replace a certain functionality, which was lost, when our user profiles were migrated to office 365. So some introducing words might be helpful.

On our sharepoint farm we had user profiles comprising a "mysite" which was essentially a personal sitecollection. There was an individual aggregated task list which displayed all tasks assigned to the user on any task list over the whole farm. A very comfortable tool to access assigned tasks from different projects, teams etc.

But I also found a version of the search center within our own farm, yielding the same results.

There is no further analogon after user profiles were migrated into office 365 by our farm admins. I wanted to build a replacement for our users to ease the life when working with assigned tasks. In fact, task lists in individual subsites make little sense if the tasks can't be aggregated automagically. Importing into outlook is no solution if you work on more than 5 projects.

My try was to make a page with a "search result" webpart to display all tasks on our sitecollection and filter it by the current user.

However I don't even get an unfiltered setup to work. No configuration of this webpart yields any result whatsoever.

[image: how it looks like]

I also tried every other option in the field "Restrict by app" as there are

- Current sitecollection
- current site
- don't restrict by app

On the contrary, normal search works on our SC.
If I use the search form and enter "ContentType=Task" I get a pretty correct list of all tasks aggregated from our sitecollection. So, where's my basic misconception of this problem.

**Update**

switching to Advanced Mode did not yield any results either.

Maybe there's some sitefeature I have to activate???

**Update**

showing the result of a normal search on top of the site collection (that's the search center, isn't it?)
[image]

This does basically what I want, but not in the form I'd like to see it. Also I can't restrict the result to those tasks assgned to the current user only.

Ok, I managed to perform a search in the search center:

[image: Search via search center]

I've got hits there, too. Note, that I limited the results by adding the number of the site collection to the search string. I wanted to see if they show up among thousands of other results from all the sitecollections.
It's also interesting, that the search center was moved to sharepoint online while the sitecollections aren't.

**Next update**
Here's what I tested in the test query box:

[image: Test query box]

I used T1 as search query. This is a task name appearing on at least one subsite also being assigned to me.

Comment: What happens when you perform that search from the Search Center? Do you get results?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I added another screenshot, showing the "normal" search results without using a webpart.

Comment: That's not your search center, that's your site collection search results page (osssearchresults.aspx) Can you do it again from the Enterprise Search Center?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I found the search center (nice pun, isn't it?) and did a search there. I get all tasks. I guess the webparts are broken somehow?

Comment: OK, When you edit the web part and add your query, are you going to the Test tab and adding a search term?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't test it during the weekend. Yes, I tried that, too. No results either. Query template="{searchboxquery} ContentType=0x0108*  AssignedTo={User.Name}". I tried with and without {searchboxquery} in the template, and with and without a term that should match in the respective test field. 0 results...

Comment: In testing your query you are populating both the query term and the UserName?

Comment: Did you use any refinable managed properties? The amount of refinable properties cross SP2013 and 365 are different. Check your refiner and query and see if you are using any custom-mapped refinable properties.

Comment: @YogaPanda No refiners at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to click the "Switch to Advanced Mode" link at the top of the web part.  Then you will see more usable options. [image]

Comment: Ok, tried exactly that. Yields zero results either.